# What is the Compton wavelength of an electron Cooper pair inside a superconductor?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, superconductivity

In [BCS theory and by experiments](https://journals.aps.org/prb/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevB.39.6425) we know that the total charge of the electron [Cooper pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooper_pair) (composite Boson) inside a superconductor is $-2e$:

$$
e_{cp}=-2|e|
$$

Also the rest mass of the Cooper pair is approximately *(i.e.without corrections applied)* twice the electron mass:

$$
m_{cp}\approx2m_{e}
$$

However, since the Cooper pair is a massive composite spin $1$ Boson (behaves more like a photon), I am not so sure if we can use the general Compton equation,

$$
\lambda=\frac{h}{m c}
$$

in order to calculate its [Compton wavelength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_wavelength) or any other meaningful wavelength associated with it.

Furthermore, the [superconducting coherence length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconducting_coherence_length) which is a measure of the size of a Cooper pair (distance between the two electrons), can be in the order of $10^{-4}$ cm depending the superconductive material. Therefore, its actual wavelength must be much larger than any calculated Compton rest value.

**Do you know how we can calculate its non-relativistic wavelength?**

Comment: https://cds.cern.ch/record/880131?ln=en

Comment: What do you want to use this wavelength *for*? There is no general rule that one must be able to associate a meaningful "wavelength" to an arbitrary quantum state.

Comment: So the Compton wavelength is 5 million times smaller than its size. If you scatter off it without breaking it apart, how will you access that wavelength?

Comment: Just to find something about the rest topology of the pair. If the coherence length ρ is close to 10^-6 m thus one micron then the matter wavelength of the pair singlet must be relative large.

Comment: You seem to associate Compton wavelength with bound state size. Recall, however, that for bottomonium, of size about 1 f, the Compton wavelength is 50 times *smaller*!  Unless you are going to utilize the Compton wavelength for Compton scattering (!) you really shouldn't be interested in it...

Comment: Any indication of actual large wavelength of the singlet (larger than the atomic lattice distance) will do. According to my ongoing research if the flux manifold of the pair is a coherent propagating large vortex ring inside the lattice this would explain the stability and immunity of the persistent superconductive current to temperature variations below the critical temperature.   There is no scattering of the Cooper pair.

Comment: What characteristic do you suggest then as more suitable for a non-relativistic Cooper pair, the  de Broglie wavelength or just the coherence length of the pair? It is my understanding that Compton wavelength is more suitable to describe particles at their rest frame.